# I installed magento 2.4.3 on windows on localhost and it gives me this error

Tags: php, html, magento2

When i try to reach the setup at localhost/magento/setup it says:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy" does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php(28): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Backend...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime.php(54): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Backend...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\Backend...') #3

Comment: There's so much stuff with Magento that's likely to cause problems with Windows - I'm surprised you got that far. Your best bet, I suspect, would be to stick a *nix distro in with WSL2 and go through that.

Comment: It maybe an issue with php8, according to the docs, magneto 2.4.3 does not support PHP 8 https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-3.html